# How to get JSON data from a url in php file.

Tags: php, ajax, getjson

Hello friends please help me for following question

1. How to pass data in JSON and how to get  JSON data in  php  using
   following code

   eg: 
   `$.getJSON("url",function(data) 
            {
                 alert(data);
            });`

php file:::::

```
<?php    how to get JSON data here?     ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below is a sample server side code i.e. php code (you asked for php)

This includes fetching data from sql and encoding it into JSON format and returning it to client.

File content of **testAJAX_getJson.php**

```
 $con =
 mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
 if (!$con)   {   die('Could not
 connect: ' . mysql_error());   }

 mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM
 Persons");

 while($row =
 mysql_fetch_array($result))   {  
 $data[] = $row;   }

 echo json_encode($data);
```